# RhodeCode failed to import extension hgcr-gui-qt

Tags: python

How to get module hgcr_ui in RhodeCode ? I have run it on my Windows box and I get an error like this:

```
failed to import extension hgcr-gui-qt: No module named hgcr_ui
```

however i can't access my repository too. I have downloaded https://bitbucket.org/glimchb/hgcr-gui too, but i still get an error like it.

Answer (score 1):

RhodeCode uses it's internal equivalent of .hgrc files in database. The table rhodecode_ui, has one available extension (largefiles) you could add similar row with hgcr_ui to that table manually and that extension should now work with RhodeCode.

Comment: thank's for answer. but now i have an error like this : "*** failed to import extension hgcr-gui-qt: cannot import name updatedir". how to corrent it ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Mercurial install is up to date. RhodeCode recommends a Python sandbox for itself, and that may have a different version.

Comment: thank's for answer. but now i have an error like this : "*** failed to import extension hgcr-gui-qt: cannot import name updatedir". how to corrent it ?